# does tuleap support interchange formats (ReqIF) or interfaces to office documents?

Tags: tuleap

I set up a tuleap for testing, to check if we can use the system for our needs.
We are missing any interchange formats (especially ReqIF) or interfaces for word/excel (to create artifacts from office documents).

Am I right, that tuleap does not support anything like this yet? I did not find any hints in the documentation or plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Tuleap currently supports csv artifact imports but nothing else. If your artifacts are in Excel, you should be able to export to csv.